# Blending artifacts in OpenCV image stitching

Tags: opencv, alpha, blending, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I am using OpenCV to blend a set of pre-warped images. As input I have some 4-channel images (*.png or *.tif) from where I can extract a bgr image and an alpha mask with the region related to the image (white) and the background (black). Both image and mask are the inputs of the Blender module `cv::detail::Blender::blend`.

When I use feather (alpha) blending the result is ok, however, I would like to avoid ghosting effects. When I use multi-band, some artifacts are appearing on the edges of the images:

[image]

The problem is similar to the one raised [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/blending-artifacts-in-photo-stitching), and solved [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6362/blurring-non-uniform-areas). The thing is, if the solution is creating a binary mask (that I already extract from the alpha channel), it does not work for me. If I add padding to the ovelap between both images, it takes pixels from the background and messes up even more the result.

I guess that probably it has to do with the functions `pyrUp` and `pyrDown`, because maybe the blurring to create the Gaussian and Laplacian pyramids is applied to the whole image, and not only to the positive alpha region. In any case, I don't know how to fix the problem using these functions, and I cannot find another efficient solution.

When I use another implementation of multiresolution blending, it works perfectly, however, I am very interested in integrating the multi-band implementation of OpenCV. Any idea of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been already reported and solved here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/89028/blending-artifacts-in-opencv-image-stitching/